# Can B1 Visa holder accompany another B1 Visa holder as dependent

Tags: usa, india, b1-b2-visas

I have a B1 Visa which is valid for another 7 years and my wife also has B1 visa which is valid for another 3 years.

I am planning to visit US for some business purpose and want to take my wife along with me.She would be taking leaves from her office and wont have any business purpose.

Is it possible? Or do I have to apply for B2 visa for her?

Comment: Do you have a B1 or a B1/B2 visa?

Comment: I have a B1 Visa